# Django fill up ChoiceField - Select html options

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am facing problem filling my select options using django forms. Even though I define choices, I don't see any choices.

My form in .py file:

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):        
    countrySignup = forms.ChoiceField( required = True,                                       
                                       widget = forms.Select( choices = ('United States', 'Jordan') ))
```

my html template has the following:

```
   <p>
        <label for="countrySignup" class="youcountry" data-icon="">Your Country </label> </br>
        {{ signupForm.countrySignup }}                  

        {{ signupForm.countrySignup.errors }}                                           

    </p>
```

and of course my view has the following code to pass the variable to template:

```
def myView(request):
    #
    # create the unbinded forms for registration
    #
    if request.method == 'GET': 
        signupForm = regForms.SignupForm()        
        return render(request,
                      "login.html",
                      {'loginForm': loginForm,
                       'signupForm' : signupForm })
```

What am I missing because I don't see any options in my select , it remains empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed the documentation that choices needs to be a list of tuples with **2 elements** each.

***choices***:
An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples to use as choices for this field. This argument accepts the same formats as the choices argument to a model field. See the model field reference documentation on choices for more details.**

this solved it:

```
countrySignup = forms.ChoiceField( choices = [('PS', 'Palestine'),
                                                 ('JD', 'Jordan')] )
```